# Access Query add record number

Tags: sql, ms-access

What’s the easiest way to add a field that act as row number to an existing access query?

The existing query is

```
Select * from myQuery
```

I’ve look around and it seems most solutions involves using the count function and requires a “ID” field, hence I’m wondering if there’s a way to do it without an ID field

Comment: This isn’t really possible because Access’ implementation of SQL is frozen-in-time since Access 2000, so it doesn’t support Window Functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` that you’ll find in all other mainstream DBMS. The only approach I know that works (which does NOT scale, btw) is to `INSERT SELECT` into a new table with an AutoNumber column.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an "easy" way.  If you have a primary key or unique column, you can use a subquery:

```
select (select count(*)
        from myQuery as q2
        where q2.pk <= q.pk
       ) as seqnum,
       q.*
from myQuery as q;
```

However, the performance is likely to be acceptable only on smallish tables.

A better alternative may be to define a temporary table with an auto-number column and then to insert the data into that table:

```
insert into myquery_table ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from myquery;
```

Comment: Any suggestions when there isn’t a primary key? i.e None of the fields are unique.

Comment: @HerbalDerp . . . The second solution of inserting into a table with an auto-incremented key.

Answer (score 0):

Though intended for a form, you might use the *RecordNumber* function from my article:

[Sequential Rows in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33069/Sequential-Rows-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

and export those records.

```
' Creates and returns a sequential record number for records displayed
' in a form, even if no primary or unique key is present.
' For a new record, Null is returned until the record is saved.
'
' 2018-08-23. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RecordNumber( _
    ByRef Form As Access.Form, _
    Optional ByVal FirstNumber As Long = 1) _
    As Variant

    ' Error code for "There is no current record."
    Const NoCurrentRecord   As Long = 3021

    Dim Records             As DAO.Recordset

    Dim Number              As Variant
    Dim Prompt              As String
    Dim Buttons             As VbMsgBoxStyle
    Dim Title               As String

    On Error GoTo Err_RecordNumber

    If Form Is Nothing Then
        ' No form object is passed.
        Number = Null
    ElseIf Form.Dirty = True Then
        ' No record number until the record is saved.
        Number = Null
    Else
        Set Records = Form.RecordsetClone
        Records.Bookmark = Form.Bookmark
        Number = FirstNumber + Records.AbsolutePosition
        Set Records = Nothing
    End If

Exit_RecordNumber:
    RecordNumber = Number
    Exit Function

Err_RecordNumber:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case NoCurrentRecord
            ' Form is at new record, thus no Bookmark exists.
            ' Ignore and continue.
        Case Else
            ' Unexpected error.
            Prompt = "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
            Buttons = vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Title = Form.Name
            MsgBox Prompt, Buttons, Title
    End Select

    ' Return Null for any error.
    Number = Null
    Resume Exit_RecordNumber

End Function
```

If a query must be used, an ID isn't mandatory if you can build a unique key by concatenating two or more fields, for example:

```
SELECT RowNumber([Field1] & "¤" & [Field2] & "¤" & [Field3]) AS RowID, *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE (RowNumber([Field1] & "¤" & [Field2] & "¤" & [Field3]) <> RowNumber("","",True));
```

using the function *RowNumber*:

```
' Builds consecutive row numbers in a select, append, or create query
' with the option of a initial automatic reset.
' Optionally, a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' 2018-08-23. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RowNumber( _
    ByVal Key As String, _
    Optional ByVal GroupKey As String, _
    Optional ByVal Reset As Boolean) _
    As Long

    ' Uncommon character string to assemble GroupKey and Key as a compound key.
    Const KeySeparator      As String = "¤§¤"
    ' Expected error codes to accept.
    Const CannotAddKey      As Long = 457
    Const CannotRemoveKey   As Long = 5

    Static Keys             As New Collection
    Static GroupKeys        As New Collection

    Dim Count               As Long
    Dim CompoundKey         As String

    On Error GoTo Err_RowNumber

    If Reset = True Then
        ' Erase the collection of keys and group key counts.
        Set Keys = Nothing
        Set GroupKeys = Nothing
    Else
        ' Create a compound key to uniquely identify GroupKey and its Key.
        ' Note: If GroupKey is not used, only one element will be added.
        CompoundKey = GroupKey & KeySeparator & Key
        Count = Keys(CompoundKey)

        If Count = 0 Then
            ' This record has not been enumerated.
            '
            ' Will either fail if the group key is new, leaving Count as zero,
            ' or retrieve the count of already enumerated records with this group key.
            Count = GroupKeys(GroupKey) + 1
            If Count > 0 Then
                ' The group key has been recorded.
                ' Remove it to allow it to be recreated holding the new count.
                GroupKeys.Remove (GroupKey)
            Else
                ' This record is the first having this group key.
                ' Thus, the count is 1.
                Count = 1
            End If
            ' (Re)create the group key item with the value of the count of keys.
            GroupKeys.Add Count, GroupKey
        End If
        ' Add the key and its enumeration.
        ' This will be:
        '   Using no group key: Relative to the full recordset.
        '   Using a group key:  Relative to the group key.
        ' Will fail if the key already has been created.
        Keys.Add Count, CompoundKey
    End If

    ' Return the key value as this is the row counter.
    RowNumber = Count

Exit_RowNumber:
    Exit Function

Err_RowNumber:
    Select Case Err
        Case CannotAddKey
            ' Key is present, thus cannot be added again.
            Resume Next
        Case CannotRemoveKey
            ' GroupKey is not present, thus cannot be removed.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error. Ignore.
            Resume Exit_RowNumber
    End Select

End Function
```